# Find all character after N match until next N match

Tags: c#

I have a long string. From this i need to find a part of string and also cut them after a certain characters. For better understanding i have added code example also with output i want from this string.

```
string myStr = "/NETGEAR-N300-WiFi-Range-Extender/dp/B00L0YLRUW/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=0606449104899&amp;qid=1548142454&amp;sr=8-1";
```

So basically i need to find the character by `/dp/` and grab after this until i find next `/`. This is the main pattern i want to use to achieve my output

//output i want like this- B00L0YLRUW

Comment: Have you looked at regular expressions? Regex class, try the patterh `"/dp/([^/]+)/"`

Comment: Can you provide answer with example? I am bad with Regex

Comment: I expect this to be a duplicate so I'd rather not post a full answer, but copy and paste this code and you should be set: `string myStr = "/NETGEAR-N300-WiFi-Range-Extender/dp/B00L0YLRUW/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=0606449104899&amp;qid=1548142454&amp;sr=8-1";
    Match ma = Regex.Match(myStr, "/dp/([^/]+)/");
    if (ma.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(ma.Groups[1].Value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you described, no need to get fancy, you can use old-school split.

```
var result = myStr.Split('/')[3]
```

However, if you string format is not so clear, regex is your friend